# How to understand the definition of divergence of a vector field on a Riemannian manifold as ${\rm d}( i_X {\rm d}V_g )=( {\rm div} X ) {\rm d}V_g$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, divergence-operator

I am trying to read some basic constructions on Riemannian manifolds, and I came across the definition of the divergence of a vector field. It is given by the formula,

$$
d( i_{X} d V_g ) = ( \text{div} X ) dV_g.
$$

Here $i_{X} d V_g$ denotes the interior multiplication of the Riemannian volume form with $X$, giving us a $(n-1)$ form. $d$ denotes taking the exterior derivative, giving us a $n$ form, and the divergence is specified to be the smooth function multiplying with the resulting $n$ form.

Can anyone she some shed on this formula? I am finding it very hard to motivate this coordinate independent definition.

Comment: This is coordinate independent because no coordinates were used in the definition

Comment: I should've been clearer. My question is why does this coordinate independent formula work? I can't seem to motivate why this makes sense in the first place.

Comment: I’m still not sure what you’re asking. You can check that it agrees with the expected formula in local coordinates. And that it satisfies the divergence theorem. Could you clarify more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sketch rather than a complete answer. You did not specify what is for you the intuitive meaning of divergence (usually some version of "flux per unit of volume") so it is a bit hard to answer. But I can think of three possibly helpful things

1. write the expression in local coordinate and convince yourself that you get the same thing as the divergence you are familiar with - essentially you are going to get $\nabla_\mu X^\mu\  \mathrm{vol}$.
2. since the volume element is closed, the expression you wrote is equal to $L_X\  \mathrm{vol}$. So, what you have is how the volume element changes when Lie transported along $X$, which is kinda of the dual viewpoint of the flux ingoing/outgoing a fixed volume element perspective.
3. By Stokes' theorem
   \begin{equation}
   \int_V d(i_X\  \mathrm{vol})=\int _{\partial V}i_X \ \mathrm{vol}.
   \end{equation}
   Now you have to convince yourself that $i_X \ \mathrm{vol}= *X$ is the flux of $X$ across $\partial V$. Something along the following lines shoud work. Write $\mathrm{vol}=n \wedge W$ with $n$ a 1-form such that the associated vector field is unit normal to $\partial V$ and $W$ is a volume form on $\partial V$. This way $i_X\  \mathrm{vol}$ once restricted to $\partial V$ is equal to $\langle X,n \rangle W $.